# show ip ospf neighbor unexpected results On packet Tracer

Tags: cisco, packet-tracer

I made a small separated networks on packet tracer and used OSPF protocol to route between networks.
Although The connect is Successful when I write 'show ip ospf neighbor' Command in CLI router X which is connected with Three networks, I get This Results:

```
Neighbor ID     Pri   State           Dead Time   Address         Interface
192.168.11.2      0   FULL/  -        00:00:33    192.168.10.2    Serial0/0/0
192.168.12.1      0   FULL/  -        00:00:39    192.168.12.1    Serial0/0/1
```

Those Are the interfaces that The router is connected to another router,
but It doesn't show The address OF the Third interface, Where The router is connected to a switch.
Image of what I mean:
[image]

is that natural or what?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have three routers.  They each have two neighbors.
What you see are not the interfaces on router X, they are the neighbors of router X.

If you want to see the OSPF interfaces on router X, type `show ip ospf interface brief`.